# И еще о болезнях

Tags: грамотная-речь

Прочитал вопрос о "лечить болезни".
А у меня другой вопрос. Тут уже обсуждалось, можно ли говорить "лечить болезни", а не "лечить человека". И пришли к выводу, что это разговорная, но вполне допустимая форма. А вот как насчет "исцелять болезни"?
Исцелять - делать целостным. То есть, если вдуматься, то это выражение может означать процесс, прямо противоположный выздоровлению.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исцелять можно человека, но не болезни. Если мы говорим о болезни, то правильно будет "исцелить от болезни", либо, совсем уж развёрнуто "исцелить человека от болезни" — именно в такой форме распространено данное выражение, а все эти "исцелить человека" и "исцелить от болезни" — его производные.

Answer (score 1):

"Лечить (что)" - не "разговорная", а вторая нормативная форма применения (первая - "лечить кого"). Второе значение слова "лечить" из словаря Ушакова:

2_ что. Принимать меры к прекращению какой-нибудь болезни. Лечить туберкулез.

"Исцелить (кого, от чего)" тем и отличается, что употребимо только к тому, "кого" лечат.

Answer (score 0):

Как вы верно подметили:

> Исцелять - делать целостным

и правильно говорит Третий глаз:

> Исцелять можно человека, но не болезни

я лишь позволю себе небольшое пояснение. Что делает болезнь? - Разрушает органы, ткани, психику, приводя этим гармонию к хаосу, при котором целостность такой системы, как **человек** нарушается. В процессе лечения целостность системы востанавливается. Это и называется **исцелением**.

Answer (score 0):

Диллема. Если написать развёрнутый ответ, получится лекция. Дать краткий? Он будет не полон. Краткость не всегда сестра таланта. Уф. Человек уникальное существо. Ему нет равных в изобретении оружия, для истребления себе подобных. Медицина не миновала чашу сию (опыты над узниками концлагерей). Для современного человека медицина это целое слово. Но мы путаем фармакологию и медицину. Задача медицины - упреждение, профилактика. Минздрав не просто так предупреждает! Надо закругляться. Исцеление - это когда человек выздоравливает без помощи фармакологии.  По сути это духовная практика. Чем мог, помог.